# Who performs currency conversion on a SEPA payment?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, sepa

To simplify, consider a

- EUR-denominated *SEPA Instant Credit Transfer*
- from a EUR-denominated account
- to a CZK-denominated account
- to a bank in the Czech Republic (EU member).

**Which institution performs the € ↦ CZK conversion?**

Bonus question: In case the institution is one of the two banks. *Is it safe to assume that the exchange rate is one of the bid/ask rates for cashless conversions published on that bank's website?*

Comment: Actually, reconsidering: I'd expect this to happen in the originating bank simply because they're the ones in a position to request the fee separately (and ensure that the desired amount reaches the destination bank) rather than effectively having to take it out of the amount being transferred.

Comment: I believe SEPA payments are (by definition) in euros, so if CZK are sent it is not a SEPA payment. With my bank I can choose which currency I want to send the money in. I don't think that just based on the IBAN number the sending bank is able to determine the currency of the receiving account. If the receiving bank receives euros for a CZK-denominated account, it will likely convert it automatically. You'd have to check with the bank of the recipient what the charge (typically this will be some percentage).

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens That's pretty much an answer, please post it as such

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens It turns out you're right. SEPA is € only. I thought I was sending money to a CZK account, but later found out that the recipient has a 'multi-currency' account that is completely hidden behind a single IBAN. No currency conversion was taking place.